# Optional first promise in Angular chain

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have 2 $http calls that return promises but the first one is optional. I believe that I have to first create a promise using `$q.defer()` but I am missing something.

Here's my non working attempt:

```
var p = $q.defer();
if (condition) {
  p = p.then(doOptionalFirst());
}  
return p.then(doOther());
```

What is correct syntax to chain these 2 calls with the first being optional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$q.when` (or [`$q.resolve`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/docs/api/ng/service/$q#resolve) with AngularJS 1.4.1) to create an already resolved promise.

```
var p = $q.resolve();
if (condition) {
    p = p.then(doOptionalFirst);
}
return p.then(doOther);
```

If you are using a deferred, you have to chain to the `.promise` and then resolve the deferred at an appropriate time.  In this case you can consider that if `condition` is true the deferred is automatically resolved.  Thus you can skip some extra possibly confusing code by just using an already resolved promise.